# C# Employee Event Program Getting Event printed

Tags: c#, class, oop

I need some help on C# programming.I am writing a small C# programming of Employee and events. Employee participating in events.The problem is that when i am selecting `DataBase display` the data base is getting Displayed but the problem is that the events participated by the employees is not getting Displayed.

I need some logic to get the Events diplayed when i select `DataBase display` in the following format.

---

Requierd Output:

```
Entire DataBase
===============
101 - Parvez Ali  -FootBall Cricket Chess
102 - Ashik Ali  - FootBall Cricket 
103 - aftab Ali  - Chricket
104 - Muhammad Ali - Chess
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Employee> empList = new List<Employee>();

        empList.Add(new Employee() { ID = 101, Name = "Parvez Ali", EventIDs = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 } });
        empList.Add(new Employee() { ID = 102, Name = "Ashik Ali", EventIDs = new List<int> { 1, 2 } });
        empList.Add(new Employee() { ID = 103, Name = "Aftab Ali", EventIDs = new List<int> { 2 } });
        empList.Add(new Employee() { ID = 104, Name = "Muhammad Ali", EventIDs = new List<int> { 3} });

        string Choice2 = null;
        do
        {
            Console.Clear();
            MenuDisplay.DisplayEvents();
            Console.WriteLine("\nPlease Enter your choice");
            int Choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Output(Choice, empList);

            Console.WriteLine("\nDo you want to Continue?(y/n)");
            Choice2 = Console.ReadLine();
        } while (Choice2 == "y");
        Console.WriteLine("GOODBYE");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public static void Output(int Choices, List<Employee> employList)
    {
        switch (Choices)
        {
            case 1:
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("List of PLayers Participated in Football");
                Console.WriteLine("========================================");
                Employee.DataBaseSearch(employList, Choices);
                break;
            case 2:
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("List of PLayers Participated in Cricket");
                Console.WriteLine("=======================================");
                Employee.DataBaseSearch(employList, Choices);
                break;
            case 3:
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("List of PLayers Participated in Chess");
                Console.WriteLine("=====================================");
                Employee.DataBaseSearch(employList, Choices);
                break;
            case 4:
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Entire DataBase");
                Console.WriteLine("===============");
                Employee.DataBaseDisplay(employList);
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input");
                break;
        }
    }
}
class MenuDisplay
{
    public static void DisplayEvents()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Menu");
        Console.WriteLine("==========");
        Console.WriteLine("1.FootBall");
        Console.WriteLine("2.Cricket");
        Console.WriteLine("3.Chess");
        Console.WriteLine("4.Display DataBase");
    }
}

class Employee
{


    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
  //  public int EventID { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<int> EventIDs { get; set; }

    public static void DataBaseSearch(List<Employee> employeeList, int Choices)
    {
        foreach (Employee employee in employeeList)
        {
            if (employee.EventIDs.Contains(Choices))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(employee.ID + " - " + employee.Name);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void DataBaseDisplay(List<Employee> employeeList)
    {
        foreach (Employee employee in employeeList)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(employee.ID + " - " + employee.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Thank You

Comment: Trivially, because it is never *told* to print - where is EventID ever used with a WriteLine? Writing the code to return collections (instead of directly printing results) will help clean up the code a good bit.

Comment: Please provide me a logic how to do it

Comment: Please provide an attempt trying to use it (EventID) for output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not displayed because in `DatabaseDisplay` you're doing absolutely nothing to display the events... After writing the name, you need to write the logic for the events.

First, you'll need a way to get the event name from the IDs. One quick way to do that is using a `dictionary`. Since the name is a `string` and the ID an `int`, a `Dictionary<int, string>` will do the job :

```
class Events
{
    public static Dictionary<int, string> EventNames = new Dictionary<int, string>{{1, "FootBall"}, {2, "Cricket"}, {3, "Chess"} }; 
}
```

Please note I'm using a private class with static public field only to stay consistent with what you already have, it's far from being a good programming practice.

After that, all you need to do is iterate on the Employee's events and display the data :

```
    public static void DataBaseDisplay(List<Employee> employeeList)
    {
        foreach (Employee employee in employeeList)
        {
            Console.Write(employee.ID + " - " + employee.Name + " - ");
            foreach (var eventId in employee.EventIDs)
            {
                Console.Write(" " + Events.EventNames[eventId]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

As you can see, after writing the name (with `Write` and not `WriteLine` because we want to stay on the same line) we can achieve that with a simple `foreach` loop. We're simply iterating on every eventIDs to get and print the value (the string name) from the dictionary created previously. Then we can create a newline to space out the data. And that's it!